# How to obtain same augmented images using ImageDataGenerator in keras or tensorflow?

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, keras

I am working with `grayscale` images of size `75 by 75` and want to perform some augmentation techniques using `ImageDataGenerator`.

But wondering if we can repeat the `output consistently` if we run multiple times. I am not talking about epochs but like running the whole code to mimic the exact same augmented images to get same results.

I am attaching `sample grayscale image`:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc, ndimage
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=10, width_shift_range=0.1, 
       height_shift_range=0.1, zoom_range=0.1, # shear_range=0.15, 
       channel_shift_range=10., horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip = True,
       rescale = 0.2, fill_mode = 'wrap')

image_path = '/trial_img.png' # grayscale image

# Obtain image
# data_format = [#num_images,height,width,#num_of_channels]
# where, #num_images = 1 and #num_of_channels = 1, height = width = 75
image = np.expand_dims(ndimage.imread(image_path),0) # add num_images dimension
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=3) # add num_of_channels dimension
plt.imshow(image.reshape(75,75), cmap = 'gray')

# Trial #1
# Generate batches of augmented images from this image
aug_iter = gen.flow(image)
# Get 10 samples of augmented images
aug_images1 = [next(aug_iter)[0].reshape(75,75).astype(np.uint8) for i in range(10)]

# Trial #2
aug_iter = gen.flow(image)
aug_images2 = [next(aug_iter)[0].reshape(75,75).astype(np.uint8) for i in range(10)]

# check if equal
truth = []
for val in range(10):
    truth.append((aug_images1[val] == aug_images2[val]).all()) # check images
np.asarray(truth).all() # check if all images are same
```

How to repeat the augmented outputs consistently in above code?

I know this code is written very badly, any suggestions on code optimization are also greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Gopi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a `seed` to the `flow` method:

```
aug_iter = gen.flow(image, seed = 0)
```

By setting this parameter to a specific integer, you will always get the same sequence of random shuffling/transformations.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the generator and save the images, then simply load the images:

```
# Trial #1
# Generate batches of augmented images from this image
aug_iter = gen.flow(image)
# Get 10 samples of augmented images
aug_images1 = [next(aug_iter)[0].reshape(75,75).astype(np.uint8) for i in range(10)]
```

If memory is not a problem, you can save this with numpy:

```
aug_images1 = np.array(aug_images1)
np.save(filename, aug_images1)
```

Then load it:

```
aug_images1 = np.load(filename)
```

If you prefer, you can save each image as proper image files (less memory occupied) using an image library such as Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image

for (im,filename in zip(aug_images1,list_of_names)):
    im = Image.fromarray(im) #make sure you have a uint8 from 0 to 255 array.
    im.save(filename)
```

Later, load the files:

```
aug_images1 = [np.array(image.open(filename)) for filename in list_of_names]
aug_images1 = np.array(aug_images1)
```

---

### Using ImageDataGenerator for loading files

In case you don't want to load all images at once in memory, with saved images, you can create a new `ImageDataGenerator`, but without any kind of augmentation, just a pure image loader.

Then use `gen.flow_from_directory()` to get images from a directory.

Read more in the documentation: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Comment: This is a good way to have consistent images, but I want to create them during runtime. Thanks for your answer, I will use this way too when needed.